# C# Access to path on another computer denied

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api2, httprequest, multipartform-data

I am currently working on Web Api 2 project.
The method I am working at is an upload image method.

Here is my code :

```
    public IHttpActionResult Upload()
    {
        string UserID = "12345";

        // LOCAL VARIABLE
        dynamic ExpObj = new ExpandoObject();

    // Virtual Directory Located on My Computer
        var FilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Images");

    // Virtual Directory Located on Another Computer (Located on LAN Network)
        var FilePath2 = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/tes2");

        if (HttpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (string file in HttpRequest.Files)
            {
                // GET UPLOADED IMAGE
                var PostedFile = HttpRequest.Files[file];

                // SET FILE NAME ( USERID + Right(FileName,10) )
                string FileName = GetFileName(UserID, PostedFile.FileName, 10);

                // SAVE IMAGE
                //PostedFile.SaveAs(FilePath + FileName);
                string ImagePath = Path.Combine(FilePath, FileName);
                string ImagePath2 = Path.Combine(FilePath2, FileName);

                PostedFile.SaveAs(ImagePath2);
                File.Copy(ImagePath2, ImagePath);

                ExpObj.imageURL = ServerUrl + ServerPath + FileName;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ErrCode = -900;
        }

        // RETURN IF GOT ERROR
        if (ErrCode < 0)
        {
            return StatusCode((HttpStatusCode)(ErrCode * (-1)));
        }

        // RETURN
        return Ok(ExpObj);
    }
```

What my method does is, it receives images as input in API using multipart form data and uploads it on server.
The directory I am using is a virtual directory

"/Images" = "\\192.168.12.28\Share Folder\PIJ Share"

"/tes2" = "C:\Dummy"

When I am trying to upload it to my own computer it works, but when I'm trying to upload it on another computer it got this error.

[Access to the path denied error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1U8u.png)

Here's what I have tried to fix it :

1. Opening Visual Studio 2013 as administrator
2. Adding permission on the specified folder (NETWORK SERVICE, IIS_IUSR, pij.api (the name of my application pool), DefaultAppPool, Everyone). I have given every user Read/Write permission.

None of these worked. I also tried to add an image file to "\192.168.12.28\Share Folder\PIJ Share" using File Exploler. And it works.
What should I do ?

Thank you very much.

**Update (1.1)**

I tried to execute the code without IIS (using localhost on visual studio 2013) and the file uploaded successfully. But when I execute it with IIS (http://api.pijmobile.local/), I get the Access to the path denied error.

It seems that the problem lies in the IIS settings. Still searching for answers.

Comment: is "/Images" = "\192.168.12.28\Share Folder\PIJ Share" supposed to read \\192.168.12.28  .. eg its a share on a machine - whats your ISS running as, as it wont have access to that share.. almost certainly

Comment: my IIS is running as ApplicationPoolIdentity (pij.api) at the moment. And I have added it as a user in the permission, and it still isn't working. I also tried to change my IIS to be running as a Network Service and adding it as a user. Still not working

Comment: did you add it to the share or just the folder?

Comment: I added both "Share Folder" and "PIJ Share" the permission for DefaultAppPool and pij.api (my current app pool). And it still gives the same error

Comment: so is 192.168.12.28 the same as the iis server?

Comment: the IIS server is located on my computer (192.168.12.38). 192.168.12.28 is another computer

Comment: The problem is you copied to the share, not IIS did.. so that proves you as a human on your account does, not that IIS can. is pij.api a domain level account?

Comment: what is a domain level account ?

Comment: Well then - thats your problem.. if you have a user on your pc called "bob" and a user on your webserver called "bob" its not the same thing.. so.. if you dont know what a domain level account is.. that would explain why its not working, you cant apply 1 machines account to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After days of researching finally I found the answer. After reading [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19830/How-to-Access-Network-Files-using-asp-net). These are the steps that I done :

1. Creating a user in my computer and the remote server (Control panel > Administrator Tools > Computer Management > In Computer management Expand the Tree " Local users and Groups" > Right Click on Users > New Users)
2. Fill the username and password

   [image]
3. Open Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager, expand your computer name, click application pools
4. Right click on your website application pool > Advanced Settings
5. In Advanced Settings Window, click the ... beside identity
6. Choose custom account > click set
7. Insert the user and password that you made earlier > OK > OK > OK

[image]

8. Thats all, you will be able to access the network share and view it.