# how to fix access to the path is denied in IIS

Tags: c#, iis

- I set up web and file folders on 2 different computers
- When I run the web on IIS, in the file download function, there is a message "access to the path xxx is denied"

[image]

My solution:

- On the computer containing the file folder I have shared full permissions for IUSR, NETWORK SERVICE, and IIS_IUSRS but it also does not work
- So please tell me what else needs to be set on the IIS side.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What authentication mode do you have enabled in IIS? And what is your application pool  identity setting?

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38848284/12219918) can help you. Go to advanced settings of your application pool and set identity to your user that access to file path.

Comment: Thanks for the help. That's right, I haven't set the permissions for application pool identity. After setting it was working fine

Comment: "I have shared full permissions for IUSR, NETWORK SERVICE, and IIS_IUSRS but it also does not work" is expected. All users/groups you set were local users/groups on that machine, so no wonder users from another machine has no access to the resources. Configure the application pool to run under a domain account and then grant that account permissions on the second machine.